# Rotate element every three weeks

Tags: javascript, date, asp-classic

I'm looking for either a classic asp or a javascript solution for this:

We want something on our webpage that rotates on a three week basis.

- Week One: Display A
- Week Two: Display B
- Week Three: Display C
- Week Four: Display A
- Week Five: Display B
- Week Six: Display C
- and so on..

I figure I can do two arrays, one like $Weeks [1,2,4,5,6,7,8... 52] and another like $DISPLAY [A,B,C,A,B,C,A,B... C], both having 52 items, grab the current week and make sure the count on the second array matches the first, but wondered if there's something more efficient? Also, I would have to reset this at January 1st and I'd rather it continue rolling.

Thanks,
Maureen

Answer (score 2):

Rather than mapping out every week of the year, why not set a baseline date then check how many weeks have passed since that day. You can then take the numberOfWeeks mod numberOfChoices:

```
var baselineSunday = new Date();
//Jan. is 0, Feb. is 1, etc.
baselineSunday.setMonth(4);
baselineSunday.setDate(5);
baselineSunday.setFullYear(2013);

var currentDate = new Date();

var diffInWeeks = GetDifferenceInWeeks(baselineSunday, currentDate);

var choices = ["A", "B", "C"];

var choiceForThisWeek = choices[diffInWeeks % choices.length];
console.log(choiceForThisWeek);

function GetDifferenceInWeeks(week1, week2) {
  var diffInMs = currentDate - baselineSunday;

  var msPerDay = (1000*60*60*24);
  var diffInDays = Math.floor(diffInMs/msPerDay);

  var diffInWeeks = Math.floor(diffInDays/7);
  return diffInWeeks;
}
```

Since the difference in weeks is based solely on the number of milliseconds since the baseline date, the rotation will continue to work into next month, year, and beyond.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BA9ym/2/)

Comment: I just discovered that this does not work in IE. Any recommendations?

Comment: @Maureen - Looks like older versions of IE can't parse a date string, lame. I updated my answer to set the baseline date parts explicitly.